# Return a view's total_rows in Drupal 7 without php filter?

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to list the total number of rows in a view into the header of the view, without enabling the PHP filter? I know I can [enable the PHP filter and output $view->total_rows in a header](http://blog.merge.nl/2009/05/13/drupal-count-views-results), but I'd like to avoid enabling the PHP filter.

I could use the [output $view->total_rows in a template file](http://knackforge.com/blog/sabareesh/how-display-views-result-count-drupal-7) but is there an existing handler or other trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On my D7 site with php-filter disabled ...

From a View configuration page:
HEADER section, add, Global Result Summary

pick total row count or whatever, whatever you want:

```
You may use HTML code in this field. The following tokens are supported:
@start -- the initial record number in the set
@end -- the last record number in the set
@total -- the total records in the set
@name -- the human-readable name of the view
@per_page -- the number of items per page
@current_page -- the current page number
@page_count -- the total page count
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tutorial](http://www.webmediahutch.com/displaying-number-pages-showing-pager-drupal-7-views) for Drupal 7 that displays the number of items and showing x-x items in Views. This is for Drupal 7 which lets you display number of pages in Views.